# Run JSON Request in the background Swift 4

Tags: ios, json, swift

I need to run this code in the background if possible. Im getting a JSON Request that sometimes takes a while to load(lag is on the server side of the URL, not the code itself.).

I want to run the code below in the background if possible. Any ideas?

```
        var stockData: Data!
        var concatTickersString = ""


        for object in dataArray.reversed() {

            concatTickersString = concatTickersString + "," + object.symbol

        }

        let url = URL(string: "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=BATCH_STOCK_QUOTES&symbols=" + concatTickersString + "&apikey=IX58FUCXKD695JY0")

        do {
            stockData = try Data(contentsOf: url!)

            let json = try JSON(data: stockData)

            if let jsonArray = json["Stock Quotes"].array {

                for ticker in jsonArray.reversed() {

                    if(jsonArray.count != 0){

                        let stockTicker = ticker["1. symbol"].string!
                        let stockPrice = ticker["2. price"].string!

                        self.watchListArray.append(WatchlistData(tickerName: stockTicker, tickerPrice: Double(stockPrice)?.currency))

                    }

                }


                tableView.isHidden = false

            }


        } catch {
            print(error)     
        }
```

Its the server of the JSON that takes long I dont think its necessarily the Data(contents of)

I tried using dispatch_async but im getting no luck.

Comment: Consider using a [`URLSession`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession)

Comment: Never use `Data(contentsOf:)`. Use `URLSession`.

Comment: Its the server of the JSON that causes lag not the Data(contents of ). Is there a way to use URLSession and run it in the background?

Comment: @husharoonie, yes, you can use data tasks from URLSession to asynchronously perform http requests. Please refer to URLSession documentation. This question is so basic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lag is caused by the fact that `Data(contentsOf:)` is a synchronous method. As [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1407864-init) says,

> #### Important
>
> Don't use this synchronous method to request network-based URLs. For network-based URLs, this method can block the current thread for tens of seconds on a slow network, resulting in a poor user experience, and in iOS, may cause your app to be terminated.
>   Instead, for non-file URLs, consider using the dataTask(with:completionHandler:) method of the URLSession class. See [Fetching Website Data into Memory](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/fetching_website_data_into_memory) for an example.

As you discovered through experimentation, placing this method in `DispatchQueue.main.async` does not make it asynchronous. Instead, follow the documentation's instruction.

This is the slightly modified example found at [Fetching Website Data into Memory](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/fetching_website_data_into_memory):

```
func startLoad() {
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.example.com/")!
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        if let error = error {
            self.handleClientError(error)
            return
        }
        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
            (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) else {
            self.handleServerError(response)
            return
        }
        if let data = data,
            let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                doSomething(with: string)
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```